# Rails 3 + JSON + Content Length not sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm using Rails for a WebApp (development with mongrel and production with nginx).
I send JSOn data with:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => { :success => "OK", :items => items } }
end
```

It works. But I need to have the Content-Length, and it's not sent. How to force the Content-Length to be sent in headers when getting JSON ? Is-it a Rails config problem, or a server config problem ?

Is there a way to set it in Rails ? Like :

response['Content-Length'] = xxx

Is it a good idea ? In my case I send a big array of JSON data (300 Kb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which Rails version (exactly)?

Try http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2011/09/rails-3-1-sending-content-length-header-using-middleware-rack-content-length/
This adds a middleware that sets the C.L. automatically.

Sure you can set it manually, but since there's that convenient middleware... :)

Also see http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/4/18/why-http-streaming - apparently it's not done automatically, all the time, because for streaming responses it's not useful.

Comment: Rails version is 3.0.5. I tried what you said before config.middleware.use Rack::ContentLength but this did nothing...

Comment: This is the actual HTTP response `{
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate";
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 09 Feb 2012 11:17:27 GMT";
    Etag = "\"fce7ad73ac9a5f1be5fd9e508ff80932\"";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Authenticity-Token" = "oD6rOpEN3Wrw4soWuyJiav8h6o+rWFPoIMW4tIStNHA=";
    "X-Runtime" = "1.537700";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge";
}`